# EF fluent API c# cascade delete issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having problems configuring a model to not cascade delete.

The modeL.

```
public class Hit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int LeadId { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("LeadId")]
    public Lead lead { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public Account account { get; set; }

}
```

Fluent API:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Hit>()
          .HasRequired(t => t.lead)
          .WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey(t => t.LeadId)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When I try to migrate it, i get this in create table on Hit:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.AccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Leads", t => t.Lead_Id)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Leads", t => t.LeadId, cascadeDelete: true)
```

What I want to achieve for both leads and accounts is this in the migration script:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Leads", t => t.LeadId)
```

How should I go about doing this? Its prbably easy, but I am new to all this:(

EDIT 1:

I added this to the fluent API:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Lead>().HasMany(i => i.Hits).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(s=> s.LeadId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Which remove cascadelete from:  .ForeignKey("dbo.Leads", t => t.LeadId)

However, I also want to remove it from:

```
 .ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.AccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
```

The easy solution would be to remove it from the migration script. But I would like how to do this with FLuent API or other methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you already use Fluent API to map your FKs, I would suggest you remove the `[ForeignKey]` attributes from your navigation properties.

Comment: Hi Florian. ANy idea on how to use fluent API to solve my "Edit 1" ?

Comment: You can do something like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<Hit>().HasOptional(m => m.account).HasForeignKey(m => m.AccountId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Comment: Also you are configuring your FKs as optional now, so you have to set the data type of your `AccountId` and `LeadId` columns to `int?`. If you don't want them to be optional change `HasOptional()` to `HasRequired()` in your FK mappings.

Comment: Your suggested fluent API gives this error:

System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.RequiredNavigationPropertyConfiguration<Account>' does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey' and no extension method 'HasForeignKey' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: Forgot the `WithMany()`, that should do it: `modelBuilder.Entity<Hit>().HasOptional(m => m.account).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.AccountId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Comment: Perfect, that worked Floarian. Drop an answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I already said in the comments above, if you use Fluent API for mapping your FKs remove the `[ForeignKey]` attributes from your navigation properties.

You can then do non-cascading mappings like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Hit>().HasOptional(m => m.account).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m
=> m.AccountId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Finally you have to check if your FK columns should be optional or required, for optional mappings change your FK properties `AccountId` and `LeadId` to data type `int?`, otherwise you have to change the `HasOptional()` part of your FK mappings to `HasRequired()`.

Answer (score 0):

Define your model like so:

```
public class Hit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

The `virtual` keyword will let Entity Framework know you are defining a foreign key and will match on Id automatically.

Remove the `HasRequired(t => t.lead).WithMany()` part from Fluent API. If a property is required it cannot exist without it and will cascade on delete.

Comment: Hi, Thx for your help.

If I remove the HasRequired and the withmany, and keep this:

 modelBuilder.Entity<Hit>()
              .HasForeignKey(t => t.LeadId)
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

then I get this error:

"does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey' and no extension method 'HasForeignKey"

Comment: On a side note: If My Lead Models Primary Key is "Id", then I assume the desired outcome should be:

.ForeignKey("dbo.Leads", t => t.Id) And not "t.LeadId". Right?:)  Or are my naming conventions ofhere, and the primary key should be named "LeadId" instead of "Id" in the Model Lead?

Comment: Hi Jan, unfortunately I cannot easily experiment with it now. If you just keep the 'Id' (I find it easiest convention for finding different properties), remove the whole Fluent API definition and define foreign key via a virtual property, and also add properties to `DbContext` definition if you did not already do that, I am quite sure they will be implemented without cascade on delete. If you put the `[required]` attribute on properties or specify in Fluent API that it has required properties, then the cascade on delete will take place.